# Permalink/Custom Post Type issue — unable to solve

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

One of the custom post types I have on a site now no longer works: the database entries still exist but I cannot access the posts. I think this is the known permalinks issue, but having been through a great many posts and having tried the solutions offered, I'm still stuck with the problem.

I have a 'single,php' file with some sorting code which then redirects to three different single files ('single-author.php', 'single-book.php', 'single-event.php').

Things I've tried:

- Switching permalink structure and switching back
- Flushing rewrite rules
- Checking rewrite rules in .htaccess

If I create a new entry in this custom post type I can see it in 'preview' but as soon as I publish it I get a 404. The problem does not seem to be affecting the other custom post types I have running on the site. Other than the recent WP update, I've not made any changes to the site.

I attach the relevant code below — any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not sure what else to try in order to fix the problem.

Many thanks!

```
add_action('init', 'authors_register');

function authors_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Authors', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Author', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Author'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Author'),
    'new_item' => __('New Author'),
    'view_item' => __('View Author'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Authors'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','revisions','excerpt'),
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'author' , $args ); 

}
```

Sorting/switching code in single.php:

```
<?php if ('post_type=book') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-book.php'); } 

elseif ('post_type=event') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-event.php'); } 

elseif ('post_type=author') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-author.php'); } 

else { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-post.php'); } ?>
```

Comment: May be the `author` name is conflict. Try to use another post-type.

Comment: Thanks Bindiya, though I'm not sure what it would be clashing with. I have a page which lists all authors, but this is 'page-authors.php' (the plural, so a different slug).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ('post_type=book') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-book.php'); } 

elseif ('post_type=event') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-event.php'); } 

elseif ('post_type=author') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-author.php'); } 

else { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-post.php'); } ?>
```

Will always return single-book.php

'post_type=books' will always return true. You must have the post_type in a variable and check for each

```
<?php 
$post_type =  get_post_type();

if ( $post_type == 'book') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-book.php'); } 
elseif ($post_type == 'event') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-event.php'); } 
elseif ($post_type == 'author') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-author.php'); } 
else { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-post.php'); } ?>
```

Also, author is not a reserved post type. The reserved post types are:

```
post
page
attachment
revision
nav_menu_item
```

Comment: Thanks @Eek – I've replaced the switching code but I'm afraid the problem still persists. Could you elaborate on the last point as I'm not sure what the implications of this are. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone offer any further help on this? I'm afraid I'm still stuck with the same problem.

Comment: First check if another post type works. `single-$posttype.php` should work by default according to the WordPress Structure -> http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png If it doesn't work, we can try to look somewhere else, if it works, then the problem is that you're making a new post type intitled "author"

Comment: Thanks @Eek — the template file for single author pages is called 'single-author.php' but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes — I have two other custom post types ('book' and 'event') which are completely fine!

Comment: Ok, so that answers your problem. It doesn't work because of "author" being a reserved named for Wordpress.

Comment: I actually don't think that's the issue as the site has been working fine with post type 'author' for around two years — it's only in the last couple of weeks that this problem began.

I tried to change the name of the post type accordingly:

`register_post_type( 'bookauthor', $args ); `

and the template to 'single-bookauthor.php' but no change.

I also notice that if I switch permalink settings to default the whole site goes down? I'm sure it's a permalink issue.

Comment: Have you updated permalinks after adding the register_post_type ? I suggest you a very good plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/ It analyzes your permalinks. In my wordpress if I hit http://*url*/author/test/ it tell's me that Wordpress Defaults is to get `author_name: test` Test Author. You should check that, maybe it will help you debug :)

Comment: Thanks @Eek, I've downloaded the plugin but I'm not fully sure to do with the information it's giving me! This is the top result:

`author/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$ 
         author: test
           page: `

Comment: Looks fine to me. That means it takes you custom post_type intitled `author` can you echo for me what does `get_post_type();` returns you on single.php ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this — my single.php has the sorting code posted above in it, though I'm not sure if this is needed? Thanks

Comment: Just 'echo get_post_type();' and tell me what it returns

Comment: It returns 'post', though that is on single-post.php — I can't check for single.php as it only has the sorting code on it.

Comment: I can do that but I've nowhere to see what it returns as single.php doesn't correspond to a page!

Comment: `single.php` is what runs on your wordpress according to you question, after that it includes different files. if you echo above the includes, the first line on the website will be your echo, before anything else.

Comment: Thanks for explaining — it's not showing anything at all (I've checked on all of the custom post types).

Comment: That's sort of impossible, have you trying to view source and see what's the first thing that appears there?

Comment: Now I've seen the names you were using. single.php never runs indeed. Can you change the name of the inclusions to not be in the form of `single-$posttype.php` ? Change single- to mytemplate- and try again :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still stuck with this problem! I've now tried switching into a fresh theme install and registering the CPT but I still have the same problem.

The info in the database is fine as I'm currently pulling it as a related field into another section of the site as a temporary workaround. Similarly, I'm running two other custom post types which are unaffected, and this one used to run perfectly.

Thanks for your help so far, Eek; if anyone has any other suggestions they're very much appreciated!